# Azure VMs doesn't ping

Tags: networking, azure, dns, virtual-machine, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm facing strange problem in Azure, I'm having 3 VMs (Domain Controller, Application server and Database Server). I've joined the 2 servers correctly to the domain Controller.

after a while i discovered that I'm not able to ping from one o the servers (DB Server) to the other servers. it reply Destination host unreachable and connection time out.

the other 2 servers are working fine between each other but not the third one.

to investigate I tried
1. Shutdown the firewall on the 3 machines. No luck
2. enable the ping rule in the firewall. No luck
3. I'm not able to telnet from this server to the RDP port to any of these servers, while I'm able to do so from the other 2 servers.
4. I tried nslookup command to see if I can communicate with the DNS Server or not. it fails with time out

Keeping in mind that
1. the 3 virtual machines are in the same virtual network and same sub-net.
2. I'v added the DNS server to the DNS Servers in the Azure Portal.

any help ?!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like perhaps the you have a machine that's no registered with the DNS server. You should be able to check this by doing an nslookup -all to get details on the machine's DNS settings. Make sure its resolving to the proper DNS machine.

Comment: I'm even trying to ping by the IP not the name.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Public Endpoints are down in state so telnet and ping won’t work. you can try to recover this machine by following the steps in this blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mast/archive/2014/11/20/recovering-azure-vm-by-attaching-os-disk-to-another-azure-vm.aspx

Hope that helps.